# Python loop to return one value from list

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding exactly how it works. let's say that I have a list of students with their IDs, names and grades as following, and I would like to make a program that lets you input the student's ID and prints out the average grade:

```
students = [ #list of id, name and grades
    ("123", "Adam", [58, 68, 74]), \
    ("925", "Bob", []), \
    ("456", "Carly", [68, 72, 100]), \
    ("888", "Deborah", [68, 99, 100]), \
    ("789", "Ethan", [52, 88, 73])
]
input_id = str(input("Enter Student id: "))
student_num = 0
while student_num < len(students):
  student = students[student_num]
  student_id = student[0]
  student_name = student[1]
  student_grades = student[2]
  if input_id == student_id:
    print(student_name, sum(student_grades)/len(student_grades))
  elif student_grades == []:
    print(student_name, "has no grades")
  else: print(input_id, "not found")
  student_num += 1
```

this outputs this result

```
> Enter Student id: 456
> 456 not found
> Bob has no grades
> Carly 80.0
> 456 not found
> 456 not found
```

How do I make it only print Carly?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the other prints in the other if branches ?

Comment: If you expect to *look up* students by ID, use a ``dict`` instead of a ``list``. Note also that you don't need the trailing ``\`` inside the list literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needed some restructuring and some extra logic

```
students = [ #list of id, name and grades
    ("123", "Adam", [58, 68, 74]), \
    ("925", "Bob", []), \
    ("456", "Carly", [68, 72, 100]), \
    ("888", "Deborah", [68, 99, 100]), \
    ("789", "Ethan", [52, 88, 73])
]
input_id = str(input("Enter Student id: "))
student_num = 0
found = False
while student_num < len(students):
    student = students[student_num]
    student_id = student[0]
    if input_id == student_id:
        found = True
        student_name = student[1]
        student_grades = student[2]
        if student_grades == []:
            print(student_name, "has no grades")
            
        else:
            print(student_name, sum(student_grades)/len(student_grades))
            
    
    student_num += 1
if found == False:
    print(input_id, "not found")
```

Comment: No prob this is pretty inefficient though even after it finds the ID it still loops through them all. It would be better if you changed the while loop to like while found == False. This way it will stop once it finds the ID.

Comment: Please don't use a counting ``while`` loop to traverse a container; directly use a ``for`` loop. When searching, instead of explicitly setting and checking a flag,  use ``break`` once the item is found and ``for`` ``else`` to trigger a "not found" case.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yep, I know this person is just learning Python however and they wanted to know how to get their code to work not the best way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and unpacking would make the code easier to read, then the 2 prints relative to the found person should be put after the `if input_id == student_id`, and the `for/else` structure can be used very nicely, if you didn't find the person you didn't use the `break` instruction (stop loop) so you go in the final `else`

```
input_id = input("Enter Student id: ")
for student_id, student_name, student_grades in students:
    if input_id == student_id:
        if not student_grades:
            print(student_name, "has no grades")
        else:
            print(student_name, sum(student_grades) / len(student_grades))
        break
else:
    print(input_id, "not found")
```

```
Enter Student id: 456
Carly 80.0
```

Comment: I get your comments, thank you!
I do wish to include the other authantications, how do I include it without "adding other prints"?

Comment: @ShoshanBen-Tzvi I got it, see the edit, that for loop is a way better practice than the while loop in the other answer